# Protractor e2e (Angular 6 Web UI) : Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

We are running e2e tests within corporate infra (behind proxy). From time to time there is an error (ng e2e --no-webdriver-update) :

```
manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
events.js:183
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
 ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443
 at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26)
```

It is possible to fix it using following commands :

```
1) webdriver-manager clean
2) webdriver-manager update --proxy http://user:password@URL:port
3) Replace projectABC\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\
with
%NODE_JS_HOME% \node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\
```

Is it possible to resolve periodic issue with driver ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add below `scripts` in `package.json`.

1) If you prefer to do webdriver update and run e2e test in single cmd, you
can config scripts as following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "wd-update": "webdriver-manager clean && webdriver-manager update --proxy http://user:password@URL:port",
    "e2e": "wd-update && ng e2e --no-webdriver-update"
  },
```

And only need to execute one cmd:

```
  npm run e2e
```

2) If you prefer to webdriver update and run e2e test in separate cmd , you can config scripts as following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "wd-update": "webdriver-manager clean && webdriver-manager update --proxy http://user:password@URL:port",
    "e2e": "ng e2e --no-webdriver-update"
  },
```

And execute two cmd:

```
  // execute `npm run wd-update` before `npm run e2e`. 
  // If you execute below cmds manually, you can skip to
  // execute `npm run wd-update` if you had succeed to execute it before.
  npm run wd-update
  npm run e2e
```

Comment: Thanks. For our case I think better to use "e2e": "ng e2e --no-webdriver-update"

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it's known issue of webdriver. You can follow the thread on GitHub: https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/260

Answer (score 0):

--no-webdriver-update option may be used in order not to update driver each time (ng e2e --no-webdriver-update)